# How to convert these string to decimal in C#?

Tags: c#

I have data from Serial, the data are : 7 5 16 0 242 48 44 10 109

Those data are sent in string format.

I need to re-convert the string to it decimal value.
But data with value 242 is read as 63.
Also for data from 128 to 255 are not correctly converted to it decimal value.

I use :

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetBytes(rxString);
```

and also :

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(rxString);

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rxString)
```

All are not working. Please help me.

Comment: Do you mean `int` instead of `decimal`? Those all look like `int` values to me.

Comment: Are those the actual byte values in the string?  If so I don't think you need to do any encoding.  But it's going to be hard to tell without example data.

Comment: @kayarista, did you find an answer for this?  If you are asking how to convert each character of the received string to its corresponding byte value (which seems to be what you're asking based one of your comments to a proposed answer below), then you can achieve this very easily by just casting each character in the string to a byte: `var byteValues = rxString.ToCharArray().Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();`.

Answer (score 1):

```
// assuming 'serialData' is your string of values...
var decimals = new List<decimal>();
foreach (var token in serialData.Split(' '))
{
    decimals.Add(decimal.Parse(token));
}
// 'decimals' is now a list of the decimal values.
```

...or if you were looking for `byte` values, you could change `List<decimal>` to `List<byte>` and change `decimal.Parse` to `byte.Parse`.

Comment: Might be better to use decimal.TryParse in case the data has errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you need array of bytes from this string (I assume from your tries), use this one-liner:

```
string val = "7 5 16 0 242 48 44 10 109";
byte[] list = val.Split(' ').Select(a => Convert.ToByte(a)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

++ use `Array.ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput> Method (TInput[], Converter<TInput, TOutput>)`

```
string[] val = "7 5 16 0 242 48 44 10 109".Split(' ');
byte[] temp = Array.ConvertAll(val, byte.Parse);
```

or

```
string val = "7 5 16 0 242 48 44 10 109";
byte[] result = Array.ConvertAll(val.Split(' ').Select(c => c).ToArray(), byte.Parse);
```

Comment: I mean that data is sent in ascii string.
Example 48 is sent as "0", 109 is "m".

I want to get back the decimal value, not in ascii string.

But if the value between 127 - 255, the decimal value was incorrect.
Such as Value 242 was read as 63. 

Thanks